# Play: migration 2.5 to 2.6: error ProvisionException

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework-2.6

I have the error when doing migration from Play version 2.5 to 2.6.

Here is list of actions I've applied:

- sbt clean
- sbt compile
- sbt update
- sbt eclipse

  I  got this exception

  ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

  1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pac4j/play/scala/Security$class
    at controllers.EntityController.(EntityController.scala:50)
    at controllers.EntityController.class(EntityController.scala:50)
    while locating controllers.EntityController
      for the 4th parameter of router.Routes.(Routes.scala:50)
    while locating router.Routes
    while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
    while locating play.api.routing.Router
      for the 1st parameter of play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.(HttpRequestHandler.scala:222)
    while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
    while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
      for the 6th parameter of play.api.DefaultApplication.(Application.scala:236)
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:235)
    while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
    while locating play.api.Application
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pac4j/play/scala/Security$class
      at controllers.EntityController.(EntityController.scala:60)
      at controllers.EntityController$$FastClassByGuice$$f46ad4b6.newInstance()
      at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
      at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
      at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
      at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1015)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
      at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:409)
      at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector$$anonfun$instanceOf$3.apply(Injector.scala:118)
      at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.withContext(Injector.scala:126)
      at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.instanceOf(Injector.scala:118)
      at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:104)
      at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:104)
      at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
      at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get$lzycompute(BuiltinModule.scala:104)
      at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:100)
      at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:99)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
      at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
      at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
      at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
      at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
      at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
      at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
      at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
      at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
      at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
      at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1085)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1015)
      at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
      at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:409)
      at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:404)
      at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector$$anonfun$instanceOf$2.apply(Injector.scala:117)
      at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.withContext(Injector.scala:126)
      at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.instanceOf(Injector.scala:117)
      at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
      at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
      at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:174)
      at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:171)
      at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
      at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:171)
      at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
      at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.play$core$server$AkkaHttpServer$$modelConversion(AkkaHttpServer.scala:183)
      at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.play$core$server$AkkaHttpServer$$handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:189)
      at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$5.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:106)
      at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$5.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:106)
      at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$23.onPush(Ops.scala:1172)
      at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:499)
      at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:462)
      at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:368)
      at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:571)
      at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:457)
      at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:546)
      at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:725)
      at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:740)
      at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:514)
      at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:650)
      at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
      at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
      at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
      at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
      at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
      at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
      at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
      at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
      at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pac4j.play.scala.Security$class
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
      ... 91 more

The class that use the Security is this

```
@Singleton
class EntityController @Inject() (val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents,
                                  val config: Config,
                                  val entities: EntityRepository,
                                  val configextractor: ConfigExtractor,
                                  val calendars: CalendarRepository,
                                  val kpis: KpiExtractor,
                                  val authz: EntityAuthorizer,
                                  val playSessionStore: PlaySessionStore,
                                  val searchService: SearchService,
                                  implicit val ec: ComputeExecutionContext
                                 ) extends BaseController with Security[CommonProfile] with KpiAware{
```

I wrote the file sbt.

```
name := """fons"""
organization := "com.luxottica.retail"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

// Dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws,
  filters,
  cacheApi,
  openId,
  guice,
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5",
  "com.github.romix.akka" %% "akka-kryo-serialization" % "0.5.0",
  "com.github.simonedeponti" %% "play26-lettuce" % "0.1",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.9",
  "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.1.0",
  "org.pac4j" % "play-pac4j" % "4.0.0",
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-http" % "2.1.0",
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-jwt" % "2.1.0" exclude("commons-io" , "commons-io"),
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-ldap" % "2.1.0",  
  "com.microsoft.azure" % "applicationinsights-core" % "1.0.10",
  "com.microsoft.azure" % "applicationinsights-logging-logback" % "1.0.10",
  "com.github.t3hnar" %% "scala-bcrypt" % "3.0",
  "org.scalariform" %% "scalariform" % "0.2.3"
)

// Test dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "2.0.0" % Test,
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % Test,
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test,
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.1" % Test
)


resolvers ++= Seq(
  "snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
  "releases"  at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases",
  "Scalaz Bintray Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
  "Simone's repos" at "https://dl.bintray.com/simonedeponti/maven"
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

scalacOptions += "-deprecation"

evictionWarningOptions in update := EvictionWarningOptions.default.withWarnTransitiveEvictions(false)


// Adds additional packages into Twirl
//TwirlKeys.templateImports += "com.luxottica.retail.controllers._"

// Adds additional packages into conf/routes
// play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys.routesImport += "com.luxottica.retail.binders._"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf")          => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$")      => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "log4j.properties"                                  => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.startsWith("meta-inf/services/") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
  case "reference.conf"                                    => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _                                                   => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

What have to change??

Answer (score -1):

We had the same problem, we fixed it upgrading Scala to 2.12

https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j/issues/207